# Get Index of a Set<String> in Swift

Tags: swift, set

```
let setOfStrings: Set<String> = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE"];
```

It doesn't behave like and array, so `setOfStrings[0]` does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sets don't have an index. You can enumerate the contents of a set or initialise an array from a set `Array(setOfStrings)` and then access the indices, but the order is undefined

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11

Comment: @Paulw11 A `Set` is a `Collection`, so does have indices (just not *integer* indices). But because the order of a `Set`'s elements is unspecified, the indices are rarely utilised directly.

Comment: @JayVDiyk From https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/set "Set: an unordered collection of unique elements."

Comment: @Paulw11 Sure, but you said sets don't have *an* index – but they do, [`Set.Index`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/set.index). A pedantic detail, I know, but I still thought it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to access the *first* element of the set as follows:

```
if let first = setOfStrings.first {
    print(first)
}
```

Assuming that you are already familiar with: Set is *unordered* data structure, i.e: `first` value is not guaranteed to be "ONE".

You cannot access an element in a set via index as an integer (`setOfStrings[0]`), however, since Set represents a [Collection](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection) (adopted by sets), [SetIndex](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/setindex) is probably what are you looking for, by using [Set.Index](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/set.index) of your current set, as follows:

```
let setOfStrings: Set<String> = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE"]
// for me, it sorted as: {"THREE", "TWO", "ONE"}

let mySetIndex = setOfStrings.index(setOfStrings.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)

let secondElemnet = setOfStrings[mySetIndex] // "TWO"
```

Note that:

- By using [subscript(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/set/2853757-subscript), you should be able to get e specific element.
- [index(_:offsetBy:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/1781645-index):

> Returns an index that is the specified distance from the given index.

- `mySetIndex` data type is `SetIndex<String>`.